# App Kill specific app by package name, clear its cache and Run the app again

Tags: android, process, kill, android-tv

I'm getting crazy while trying to make an app that will

1. kill specific other app
2. clear the killed app cache
3. restart the killed app again

for Android TV 10

lets call this app "the killer app"

i'm testing this app in android x86 emulator inside the android studio

i successed to kill the app but the app won't run even i enabled permissions for the killer app
thats the code i wrote:

```
package com.deliadsolutions.cachekillerstarter

import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity


/**
 * Loads [MainFragment].
 */
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity()
{
    final var hotpackagename= "il.net.hot.hot"
    fun startNewActivity(context: Context, packageName: String)
    {
        var intent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
        if (intent == null) {
            // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
            intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

//        Toast.makeText(this, .cacheDir.path.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val am = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        am.killBackgroundProcesses(hotpackagename)
        this.cacheDir.deleteRecursively()
//        var intent = this.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(hotpackagename)
//        this.startActivity(intent)
        //val launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(hotpackagename)
        //startActivity(launchIntent)`
        val ctx: Context = this // or you can replace **'this'** with your **ActivityName.this**

        try {
            val i = ctx.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(hotpackagename)
            ctx.startActivity(i)
        } catch (e: Exception)
        {
            // TODO Anerated catch block
        }


        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        val cn = ComponentName()
        intent.component = cn
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)

        this.finishAffinity()

        

    }

}
```

none of these app run methods starting the app

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Cachekillerstarter" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PlaybackActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BrowseErrorActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple issues here:

- The [`CLEAR_APP_CACHE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#CLEAR_APP_CACHE) permission has protection level `signature|privileged`, i.e. there's no way of granting that to a 3rd party app without rooting.
- The [`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission is similar but a bit more nuanced.
- Killing background processes might not actually kill the main process of the other app, can't find much documentation on that though. (btw. starting from Android 14, 3rd party apps can't kill other apps)
- `this.cacheDir.deleteRecursively()` deletes your apps own cache, not the one of the target application.

Your code is a bit confusing:

- `startNewActivity` is never called, but the `if(intent == null)` block creates an Intent without any info besides the action.
- Similarly, the last block of code creates an Intent without a target package and an empty component name, which wont do much.

The conclusion I'm reaching here is due the limitation of the `CLEAR_APP_CACHE` permission, you won't be able to do what you want regardless.

---

You won't get any further help unless you post some logs, you say the app won't run, but seeing that you have a call to `this.finishAffinity()` at the end, I'm figuring the app just immediately closes after starting.